# Using interfaces to define partial functions on Type

Tags: typeclass, idris, type-level-computation

I'm trying to define *something* in Idris which would provide a way to represent types typographically. Think about `Show`, but instead of `Show`ing elemenents of a type, I want to show the type *itself*. That would have the same practical effect of having defined a partial function on `Type` (that gives a type's representation) that a user could extend for their types as well.

My first idea, given the “user can extend functionality” requirement, was to use interfaces. So that would look something like this:

```
interface Representable a where
  representation : String
```

Some possible implementation would be

```
Representable Nat where
  representation = "Nat"
```

However, I come to a problem. Let's say I want to define a representation of the function type. That would be the representation of its domain, an arrow, and a representation of its range. So something like

```
(Representable a, Representable b) => Representable (a -> b) where
  representation = representation ++ " -> " ++ representation
```

The problem is now obvious. The compiler can't infer the `representation`'s types on the right-hand side.

One alternative I came up with would be to create a `Representation` type that would carry an “artificial” argument:

```
data Representation : Type -> Type where
  Repr : (a : Type) -> String -> Representation a
```

Which would lead to

```
interface Representable a where
  representation : Representation a
```

And then

```
Representable Nat where
  representation = Repr Nat "Nat"

(Representable d, Representable r) => Representable (d -> r) where
  representation = Repr (d -> r) $
    (the (Representation d) representation)
    ++ " -> "
    ++ (the (Representation r) representation)
```

But then, off course, I get the error

```
Representations.idr:13:20-127:
   |
13 |   representation = Repr (d -> r) $ (the (Representation d) representation) ++ " -> " ++ (the (Representation r) representation)
   |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of Representations.Representations.d -> r implementation of Representations.Representable, method representation with expected type
        Representation (d -> r)

When checking argument a to constructor Representations.Repr:
        No such variable d
```

However, I want `representation` to be argumentless – obviously, as it is a representation of the *type*, not its elements.

Does anyone have any sugestion on how to fix this particular error, or better yet, how to implement my idea in some not-so-horrifying-way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take an idea from Haskell and use a [proxy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html) to pass a token to `representation` with no term-level content:

```
data Proxy a = MkProxy

interface Representable a where
  representation : Proxy a -> String

Representable Nat where
  representation _ = "Nat"

(Representable a, Representable b) => Representable (a -> b) where
  representation {a = a} {b = b} _ = representation (MkProxy {a = a}) ++ " -> " ++ representation (MkProxy {a = b})
```